# Spring boot Rest Template offset and limit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am Working on Spring boot application and have to call client rest service there could see 10000 records.But i need to call their service using rest with limit of 50 records at time and next 50 records and so on up to 10000 records.Kindly please share your input on this.

Comment: Contact the maintainers of that rest service and check if that is possible. You can want it but if it isn't supported it just isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends with how you want to do the limit. If you're using native Queries you can limit in the query. However this approach is not that smart because you'd need the pther data later. The smart idea is to limit in the view using approaches like pagination which are available in nearly all frontend or templating engines In case of spring thymeleaf together with technologies like bootstrap support pagination to limit results and view level rather than at api level